# Help identify this (probably Confederate) sword?

Tags: identification, cavalry, sword

[image: cavalry sword]I inherited this sword from my uncle.
It is by S & K (Schnitzler & Kirschbaum) with the inspector stamp of 'F.C' although the 'F' is not clear to me.
Is it a copy?

**Measurements are:**

Blade is 89cm and 107cm with handle, 3cm wide and 1cm thick closest to handle.

If you know anything about this sword(type of sword), I would very much like to hear it.

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks kindly

Comment: Is there a reason you think this may be U.S. civil war?  This manufacturer (being out of Germany) also sold to European countries as well.

Comment: If you are looking to establish a value, be aware that the confederate cavalry sabers that bring big money were made in the confederacy during the war. They are quite rare, and often faked.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with this identification is the number of possibilities. Knowing the manufacturer leads us to several options. They absolutely *did* sell to the US, and many similar weapons can be found through some googling. One site [AntiqueGuns.com](http://www.antiqueguns.com/index.php/view-auctions/categories/gold-rush-through-civil-war/civil-war-edged-weapons-swords-bowies-and-bayonets/page-1554), has what appears to be a matching weapon, listed as an **heavy cavalry saber** of Civil War **era**. The entry also has a lot of good background info on the company S&K, and a possible reference source to look at in the book [CIVIL WAR CAVALRY & ARTILLERY SABERS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0917218922) by John J. Thillmann.

Unless you offer a reason why you think its American, I will also offer an alternative to this being a US civil war weapon. The model you have seems to be a very good match to one for sale at this site, [Bygone Blades](http://www.bygoneblades.com/buy-sampk-italian-1860-heavy-cavalry-sabre). This weapon is listed as an **Italian 1860 Heavy Cavalry Sabre by Schnitzler & Kirschbaum**. The images there show the exactly matching pommel, grip including the small rectangular cutout visible on the hand guard in you image, spear type point, *and* list the length at 89cm, matching your measurements exactly.

Whether or not this weapon was made for the American market or for the Italians, (or some others I haven't found yet) I think we can be confident in the 1860 **Heavy Cavalry Sabre** identification.

As to authenticity, I absolutely concur with the other answer. That should be left to a hands-on inspection by an appropriate expert.

Answer (score -1):

Some quick google foo:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/RARE-CIVIL-WAR-ERA-S-K-SCHNITZLER-KIRSCHBAUM-HEAVY-CAVALRY-SABER-DRAGOON-/321031644009

- A claimed K and S cavalry sword being sold on EBay. Looks similar in style to the OP's particular in the handle.

http://www.horsesoldier.com/products/edged-weapons/swords/12901

- Example of a verified sold K & S sword similar time period baring much of the same appearance.

http://howardlanham.tripod.com/link11d.htm

- A description of the Unions purchase order of K&S swords for the civil war. Link also contains a blueprint of swords related to ranks. The NCOs shape on this blueprint is similar to the OPs.

Based on all that is provided I venture to guess what you have is a Union NCO sword. This particular maker in keeping with convention of the times created different styles of blades which were indicative of various specialties and rank. The level of ornamentation of the blade and scabbard also reinforces my conclusion of it being an NCO sword.

As with most swords the most revealing information lies in the handle and makers mark, which yours ~appear to look akin to. I also like the weather condition of your guard as that is ~good sign towards its authenticity.

However, I nor can anyone online really judge the sword to be authentic. I suggest taking it to an auction house or authentication service if you wish to have it verified.

Comment: Please explain what you found at these links that makes you come to this identification of this item.  If the links break your answer needs to stand on its own.